# libwebp.so.6 Import error in Raspberry Pi 3b

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

I wrote a piece of code to recognize my face in python3 using opencv, imutils and other libraries.
When I put that code on Raspberry Pi 3b and compile it, this error shows up :

```
  File "detect_drowsiness.py", line 7, in <module>
    from imutils.video import VideoStream
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imutils/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libwebp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

These are the imports I am using :

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import playsound
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2
```

I installed every library one by one using `pip3` on raspberry pi

Python version : 3.5.3

opencv version : opencv-python==3.4.4.19

Please ask for any further details you might need.

Answer (score 13):

You're missing the libwebp-dev package. For installing it you should open a terminal and write:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev
```

Comment: helped me installed opencv-python on the raspberry pi. thanks